# Use of enums in c

Tags: c, enums

I have this enum:

```
  enum Seasons{
  winter,spring,summer,autumn
  };
```

what will this code do?

```
 enum Seasons curr_season;
 curr_season = autumn;
 curr_season = 19;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  That's not a bad starting point if you want to find out what something does.

Comment: It won't "do" anything; there are no side effects.  But it is perfectly legal C.

Comment: If your compiler chooses to make the enum wide enough to be able to take values in the range 0 to 19 (most likely), your code will overwrite the value `autumn` (same as `3`) with `19` in the object `curr_season`; otherwise it is UB and anything can happen.

Comment: @pmg: I think "always" rather than "likely".  An enum must be at least as big as a `char`.

Comment: Ah, the disappointment of C enum........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum Seasons{
    winter,spring,summer,autumn
};
```

The above creates the following

```
winter=0, spring=1, summer=2 and autumn=3
```

NOTE: `enums` are just integers! .. It can take negative numbers also!

```
enum Seasons curr_season;
curr_season = autumn;
/* curr_season will now have 3 assigned */

curr_season = 19;
/* curr_season will now have 19 assigned */
```

You can run the following code to check this!

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Seasons{
        winter,spring,summer,autumn
};

void print_seanons(void)
{
    printf("winter = %d \n", winter);
    printf("spring = %d \n", spring);
    printf("summer = %d \n", summer);
    printf("autumn = %d \n", autumn);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    enum Seasons curr_season;
    print_seanons();

    curr_season = autumn;
    printf("curr_season = %d \n", curr_season);
    curr_season = 19; 
    printf("curr_season = %d \n", curr_season);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Enums constants are of type `int` in c. Although `enum`s are not explicitly of type `int`, the conversion between enumerated types, and `int`s is silent. There is usually no constraint checking on enums, so your code is functionally equivalent to:

```
int curr_season;
curr_season = 3;
curr_season = 19;
```

Comment: enum constants are of type int, but enum types are implementation defined integer types.

Comment: `enum`s are not of type `int`.

Comment: But in c they are freely convertable to int

Answer (score 0):

Enums are integral values, so it will assign the value 19 to `curr_season`.

Cross use (assigning integer values to an enum) is considered poor programming practice and should be avoided.